# Query data without opening up database?

Tags: openlayers-2, leaflet, carto, tilemill, mapbox

I have a bunch of polygon data that I want users to be able to sort/filter based on certain criteria.

I have the data in a CartoDB table, and can pretty easily use some SQL calls to achieve what I want.  The only problem is that my CartoDB table has to be set to public for this to work, meaning someone could dump the data from my table pretty easily.

So I'm wondering if there's some way I can send the polygon data from CartoDB into some other service, which could filter the query/filter data without opening up my table?

My apologies if this question isn't clear..

Answer (score 1):

Sure, if you are using a server-side programming language like PHP (or Java or .Net) you could have a page which make the requests to CartoDB and return the results to the user.

So, the user would request the page from your server. The page on your server would request the data from CartoDB. CartoDB would send it to your server and your server would send it on to the user.